# C#: Chained Linq methods and casting

Tags: linq, casting, plinq

I have a little game, where I implemented some collision detection. Now I want to get a list of all items of a specific type, which are colliding with the current "Entity" object. I want to do something like this:

```
    public List<T> GetCollidingObjects<T>() where T : Entity
    {
        return this.Game.World.Entities
            .AsParallel()
            .Where(e => e.IsColliding(this))
            .Where(e => e is T)
            .ToList<T>();
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Instance argument: cannot convert from "System.Linq.ParallelQuery<GameName.GameObjects.Entity>" to "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>"
```

Can anyone explain, why this happens?

Thank you!

Comment: It probably won't solve your problem, but the second `Where` clause can be replaced with `OfType<T>()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use `ToList()` like that.  The generic parameter you supply (if you choose to do so) must match the type of the sequence.  It's a sequence of `Entity`, not `T`.

Anyway, you should use `OfType()` to do the filtering, that's what it's there for.

```
public List<T> GetCollidingObjects<T>() where T : Entity
{
    return this.Game.World.Entities
        .OfType<T>()
        .AsParallel()
        .Where(e => e.IsColliding(this))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: +1: Also, depending on the scenario, it will likely be better to put the `.OfType<T>()` before the `.AsParallel()`, as the partitioning will likely do a much better job, especially if there is a non-random distribution of types within Entities (highly likely).

Comment: @Reed: Ah good point.  I was debating on whether `OfType()` should come before or after `AsParallel()`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation :-) It works great! And I understood why it did not work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Mercado's answer is correct, but can be stated more plainly.

```
.Where(e => e is T)
```

This call to `Enumerable.Where<Entity>` returns an `IEnumerable<Entity>` (a filtered version of the source, which is an `IEnumerable<Entity>`).  The call does not return an `IEnumerable<T>`.

`Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>` and `Enumerable.OfType<TResult>` can return an IEnumerable with a type different than the source:

```
.Where(e => e is T)
.Select(e => e as T)
```

or

```
.Select(e => e as T)
.Where(e => e != null)
```

or

```
 .OfType<T>()
```